# F# equals operator complexity

Tags: f#, complexity-theory, equals, operator-keyword, user-defined-types

I have a question about default "**=**" (equals) operator in F#. It allows to compare user-defined union types. The question is: what's the complexity of it? For example, let's consider following type:

```
type Tree<'a> =
  | Nil
  | Leaf of 'a
  | Node of Tree<'a> * Tree<'a>
```

and following trees:

```
let a : Tree<int> = Node (Node (Node (Leaf 1, Leaf 2), Node (Leaf 3, Node (Leaf 4, Leaf 5))), Node (Leaf 6, Nil))
let b : Tree<int> = Node (Node (Node (Leaf 1, Leaf 2), Node (Leaf 3, Node (Leaf 4, Leaf 5))), Node (Leaf 6, Nil))
let c : Tree<int> = Node (Node (Node (Leaf 1, Leaf 2), Nil), Node (Node (Leaf 3, Node (Leaf 4, Leaf 5)), Leaf 6))
```

It is obvious that this code:

```
printfn "a = b: %b" (a = b)
printfn "a = c: %b" (a = c)
printfn "a = a: %b" (a = a)
```

produces this output:

```
a = b: true
a = c: false
a = a: true
```

I expect that the "*a = b*" and "*a = c*" comparsions takes the linear time. But what about "*a = a*"? If it is constant what about more complex structures, like that one:

```
let d : Tree<int> = Node (a, c)
let e : Tree<int> = Node (a, c)
```

Will it go through whole *d* and *e* structure or will it stop at "*a = a*" and "*c = c*"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# uses structural equality whereas the default `Equals` implementation in .NET uses reference equality. This means, in the typical case, equality comparisons are *O(N)* where *N* is the number of fields in the object graphs being compared.

If you want to ensure `a = a` is optimized, you can override `Equals` to check for reference equality first, and fall back on structural equality otherwise. You'll need to annotate your type with `[<CustomEquality>]`.

You can see the rather lengthy implementation of structural equality in [the F# source code on github](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L1313-1685). To follow the call hierarchy start with [`GenericEqualityObj` on line 1412](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L1412-1441).

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** The original answer was wrong.

The usual implementation of `Equals()` in .Net works like this:

- Compare the two instances by reference. If they both refer to the same object, return `true`.
- Compare the runtime types of the two instances. If they are different, return `false`.
- Compare each of the fields of the type pairwise for equality. If any are not equal, return `false`, else return `true`.

For some reason, F# skips the first step, which means the time complexity is always linear.

Since the compiler knows that `a` and `b` are the same and some subtrees of `c` are same as some subtrees of `a`, and it also knows that they are immutable, it could theoretically make `a` and `b` the same object and reuse some of their parts in `c`. The runtime does something similar with strings, called [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). But (based on decompiled code) it seems the compiler currently doesn't do this.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but the "usual implementation of `Equals`" you described doesn't apply to F# unions.

Comment: Why not? It behaves exactly like that.

Comment: Yes, `Equals(obj)` does, but for types implementing `IStructuralEquatable<T>` (records, unions, etc) `(=)` calls `Equals(obj, IEqualityComparer)` instead. Its implementation is provided by the compiler and, and far as I can see, doesn't include a check for reference equality.

Comment: @Daniel, you're right. And `Equals(obj)` doesn't check for reference equality either. I have no idea how did I overlook that.

Comment: You're right about `Equals(obj)`. I thought it falls back to `obj.Equals` but it actually calls `Equals(T)`, which is more or less `Equals(obj, IEqualityComparer)` with a type test. Man, too many `Equals` methods...

Comment: The usual version of `Equals` on .Net is that you inherit an implementation from `Object` that just does `ReferenceEquals`.

Comment: @Brian - is there any reason why structural equality in F# doesn't start with `ReferenceEquals`?

Comment: @StephenSwensen a == a is not always true.  NaN, for example, should return false when compared to NaN.  You'd have to ensure that every included element in a record satisfies a requirement that (a always is equal to itself).  I have no idea how you'd do that in a compiler, since any class can provide arbitrary code for equality.  [Maybe you could do it for very restricted subsets of records; records that only use builtin types that are guaranteed to always be equal to themselves?]